# MSSQL Replication - Transactions

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, master-slave

I have a simple replication architecture to test replication via transactions. I have one Distributor database (Master) and two Subscriber databases (Slaves). Each time the Master performs a write, it pushes these writes to the Slaves.

If Slave DB 1 is down for whatever reason, and Master DB continues prodding along with 1000x more transactions. If I bring Slave DB 1 back up, how does it keep up to date with the Master DB with the transactions that it missed while down?

Comment: This site has all the info you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/sql-server-business-continuity-dr?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Each subscriber keeps track of the latest log sequence number (LSN) that was last successfully delivered. When the distribution agent runs for a specific subscription, it asks of the distributor "give me commands that have happened as of this LSN". And, assuming that the distributor has them, it will start delivering them for replay at the subscriber.

One caveat is that a property of the distributor is a retention period. It's the amount of time that the distributor will keep commands before they qualify for cleanup. If the subscriber is offline longer than that retention period, catch up for that particular subscriber will not be possible and it will need to be re-initialized.